# .BAT: Получение и форматирование списка папок

Tags: файлы, cmd, bat

Необходимо, чтобы функция получала список папок, начинающихся только с @ и форматировала к виду:

```
abc="@folder1;@folder3;@folder5;..."
```

Comment: распарсить команду **"dir /ad @*"**

Comment: Так в чем вопрос то!? Что у Вас не получается?